# Is the compression used for gzip and zip binary compatible?

Tags: zip, gzip, file-format

I've got a lot of files which are being produced direct to gzip format.  I'd like to re-package these into zip archives grouping many files together.

Given the size and volume of these files *(0.5GB uncompressed per file and thousands of files)* I really want to avoid decompressing these only to re-compress them if the only technical difference is the file headers.

Given that both file formats use / support the [Deflate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) algorithm, is it possible for me to simply strip the file header off a gzip file and patch the compressed data into a zip file without re-encoding (but adding an appropriate header entry).  Or is there a difference in the binary encoding of the compressed data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the compressed data from gzip files directly to construct a zip file.